# Regular expression how to get filepath

Tags: c#, regex

I have a config file like:

```
#time(Second or HH:ss:mm)  exepath
5 c:\windows\notepad 
18:38:00   c:\windows\notepad.exe
18:38:00   "c:\path\path path2\program.exe" command
```

I want to get time ,filepath and command by regex. I tried:

```
string line = "18:38:00   c:\windows\notepad.exe.....";//from config file
string reg = @"(\S*)("")?(.*)("")?";

Regex regex = new Regex(reg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match m = regex.Match(str);

 if(m.Success)
  {
      Console.Write(" {0} ", m.Groups[1]);
      Console.Write(" {0} ", m.Groups[2]);
      Console.Write("/n");
  }
```

but that is not work

Comment: @AvinashRaj I hope to get the time , the file path and command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add the pattern to match in-between space.

```
@"(?m)^(\S*)\s*""?([^""\n]*)""? *(.*)?$"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dI1cP2/7)

Comment: Think you,but when the path has space ,it got the wrong filepath,like 18:38:00   "c:\path\path path2\program.exe" i will get 18:38:00,c:\path\path,path2\program.exe